# How to Construct an std::variant type object whose itself Templated and constructor forwards arguments

Tags: c++

I have defined `var_t` to be of type `std::variant< Fum<Bazz>, Fum<Ack> >`. The templated class `Fum<>` should forward its constructor arguments to Bazz and Ack, so it can create them emplace. However, I get the following error:

`[g++ default #1] error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast`

### Bazz and Ack Definitions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>


// Bazz
// C'tor takes in float

struct Bazz {
    float f;

    Bazz(float)
    {
        std::cout << "Bazz Main" << std::endl;
    }

};

// Ack
// C'tor takes in std::string

struct Ack {
    std::string str;

    Ack(std::string strParam)
        :str(strParam)
    {
        std::cout << "Ack Main" << std::endl;

    }

};
```

### Fum Definition:

```
// Fum<>
// Variadic C'Tor should forward args to value of type T

template<typename T>
class Fum {
public:
    T value;

    template<typename ... Params>
    Fum<T>(Params&& ... argsForT)
        :value(std::forward<Params>(argsForT)...)
    {std::cout << "FUM C'TOR" << std::endl;}
};
```

### var_t Definiton:

```
typedef std::variant< Fum<Bazz>, Fum<Ack> > var_t;
```

### The Following Code Works:

```
// Fum forwards string to Ack as expected and creates Ack emplace.
int main() {
    Fum<Ack>(std::string("Hello, World!"));
}

// >>>> Ack Main C'Tor
// >>>> Fum C'Tor
```

### The Following Does NOT Work:

```
int main() {
    var_t((std::string("Hello, World!")));
}


// [g++ default #1] error: no matching conversion for functional- 
// style cast
```

I believe `Fum` templated C'Tor is causing ambiguity. Therefore, var_t does not know if it should construct `Fum<Ack>` or `Fum<Bazz>`. But I'm not sure. So how can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest you reduce the shown code. It is a little bit verbose, most method definitions are not useful in the context of this problem

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at [`in_place`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) for variant construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) has a proper overload for *emplace constuction*.

In particular:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
constexpr explicit variant(std::in_place_type_t<T>, Args&&... args);
```

So your code could be fixed with:

```
var_t(std::in_place_type<Fum<Ack>>, std::string("Hello, World!"));
```